# JavaFX Dynamic add of Rows and Columns to TableView

Tags: java, excel, javafx, tableview

I am trying to develop a piece of code to import/export data from Excel files into Java. I've completed importing and exporting into defined templates (example: Class Employee, where I know that the Excel sheet has the "id" in column1, "name" in column2, and so on).
What I am having trouble is adding columns and rows in order to make the TableView have the same information as the imported Excel file, no matter the number of rows/columns.

When I import data from an Excel file I send it to an 'ArrayList parameter'. So if Excel file has:

Id | Name

1 | John

2 | Mary

When I list the ArrayList 'parameter' I get: "Id Name 01 John 02 Mary"

I know how many columns I have from (since All Cells = Row Number * Column Number):

```
columnSize = parameter.size() / importedExcel.RowNumber()
```

I've managed to add columns dynamically according to generic Excel files.

```
public class ExcelObject {
private int rowNum;
private ArrayList<String> parameters;

public void readExcel(String filePath, int sheetInt) {
    try {

    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetInt);

    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

    while (rowIterator.hasNext())
    {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();
        this.incRowNum();

        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

        while (cellIterator.hasNext())
        {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
              case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        this.parameters.add(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                            this.parameters.add(cell.getDateCellValue().toString());
                        } else {
                            this.parameters.add(Double.toString(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                        }
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        this.parameters.add("" +cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                        break;

                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                        this.parameters.add(cell.getCellFormula());
                        break;

                    default:
                        System.out.println("ERROR");
                }
            }
        }
        file.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class vfUIController implements Initializable {
private ExcelReader read;

@FXML
private TableView table = new TableView();

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();

    ExcelObject obj = new ExcelObject();

    obj.readExcel("file.xlsx", 2);

    for (int i = 0; i< obj.getColumnNum; i++) {
        columns.add(obj.getParametersValue(i));
        System.out.println("ADDED COLUMN:" +i);
    }

    ArrayList<TableColumn> columns = new ArrayList<TableColumn>();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < obj.getColNum() ; i++) {
        columns.add(new TableColumn(obj.getParameters().get(i)));
    }

    table.getColumns().addAll(columns);

    //missing code to add rows from 'ArrayList<String> parameters' at obj.getParameterValue(int arrayListPosition)

}
```

But I can't seem to add any Rows using `table.setItems()` or other methods. I get blank rows all the time.
I'm not sure if I'm failing by not using `setCellValueFactory` properly or because the whole method I use to import cells data into an ArrayList is not smart.

In summary I would like to import any Excel file information into a TableView in JAVA.

Thanks for the help.
Simon

Comment: You say you don't know if you are using `setCellValueFactory` properly, but I don't see you calling that. Can you post that code?

Comment: I'm not using it at all in the actual code. I couldn't find a way of inserting the rows with or without setCellValueFactory

Comment: Without a `cellValueFactory` the table columns won't have any data to display. You need to set a `cellValueFactory` on each column.

Comment: But how can I set cellValueFactory if the data is all gathered in an 'ArrayList<String> parameter'. I can't "attach" a column to the var 'parameter' or i'll have all the information from the Excel file into a single column.

Comment: Just get the respective element from the array list, wrap it in a `ReadOnlyStringWrapper` and return it from the factory. Similar example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255870/how-to-populate-tableview-from-list-of-string-in-javafx

Answer (score 0):

In you code you have only added empty columns to your Table View.
in order to fill your table with a data.
you have to set table data like this :

```
 private TableView<your Object type> table = new TableView<>();
List<your Object type> list=new ArrayList<>();
```

fill you list and then:

```
 ObservableList<your Object type> fxlist=FXCollections.observableList(list);


table.getItems().addAll(fxlist);
```

Data object Type must be the class that represents each row of data.
Your list must be filled by you exsl data.